# JQuery keyboard event code property is always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) keyboard events do have a `code` property which returns a string constant like `"KeyA"` if the `A` key has been pressed. However, in my JQuery keyup event handler the property code is always undefined:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.code === 'KeyA') // unfortunately always undefined
      console.log('Key "A" pressed');
});
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.code === 'KeyA')
    console.log('Key "A" pressed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>KeyboardEvent code Property</h1>

<p>Press a key on the keyboard in this snippet.</p>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there no way to obtain the "KeyA" string constant from a JQuery keyboard event?

Comment: What browser are you using? Internet Explorer does not support the native "code" property.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 80/81.

Comment: You edited out a **working snippet** that demonstrated that `e.originalEvent.code` does in fact work.

Comment: Yep, because my question would have looked rather weird after editing out that "e.originalEvent.code" doesn't work. It does, I had a typo in it.

Comment: OK, well then the outcome is that `e.originalEvent` is the solution. The jQuery library, for whatever reason, does not copy the "code" property to its event wrapper object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`event.code` seems working!

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.code === 'KeyA')
    console.log('Key "A" pressed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

Comment: MDN says that IE does not support the "code" property, which may be the OP's problem.

Comment: What is `event` in that case? Is this some kind of global variable?

Comment: @D.R. yes, but I edited this answer to use `e.originalEvent` and it works fine.

Comment: Ah, yes, `e.originalEvent.code` is something different than `event.code`.

Comment: @D.R. actually no it isn't, because `event` and `e.originalEvent` refer to the exact same object, the browser-generated native event.

Comment: Ok, it's some kind of magic global variable then. Thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

The event object in your jQuery event handler is a [wrapper object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) created by jQuery. You can get the actual event object generated by the browser from `e.originalEvent`. It appears that jQuery does not provide a "code" property on its wrapper.

The "which" property of the jQuery event object is normalized by the library so that it reliably supplies the character code corresponding to the key.

The linked [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) indicates that the `originalEvent` property should have a "code" property working as described *if* you're using a browser other than Internet Explorer. The code snippets added to the OP and in an answer or two show that it works as documented for me in Firefox.

Comment: I already posted in my initial question that `e.originalEvent.code` is also undefined. Indeed that's weird: `JSON.stringify(e.originalEvent)` returns `{"isTrusted":true}` only, which are far too few properties?!

Comment: According to the sample in the docs https://api.jquery.com/keyup/ the code property should exist even in JQuery though!

Comment: @D.R. On the event object page, you'll see you can get `charCode`; I don't see any mention of a "code" property on that link you just posted.

Comment: See the example on the bottom of the page. There is a code property shown.

Comment: @D.R. also `JSON.stringify(e.originalEvent)` won't work properly because that event object — the native one — is not an ordinary JavaScript object. If you `console.log()` it directly, you'll see all the properties that are actually available.

Comment: @D.R. I have added a snippet in your post. `e.originalEvent.code` seems to work fine for me on Chrome latest.

Comment: Hmm, `e.originalEvent.code` now works on my machine as well...maybe I had a typo in it before.

Comment: I'm still bazzled though why `e.code` does not work when it does so on the docs page. See https://imgur.com/a/HLcpvFC

Comment: @D.R. Have you tried the code snippet edited into your original question? Or on the other answer? The `originalEvent.code` property works as you expect, at least for me in Firefox.

Comment: Yep, it does, I said so three comments before this one. I had a typo in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate life ?!
Instead of:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.code === 'KeyA') // unfortunately always undefined
      console.log('Key "A" pressed');
});
```

Try this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
      if(e.which == 65) // 65 is A's keycode.
         console.log('Key "A" pressed');
   });
</script>
```